# How to view hub.docker.com image descriptions via CLI?

Tags: linux, docker

I'm new to docker and was wondering if there's an easy way to view the image description on hub.docker.com from the CLI (similar to executing `apt info mariadb-server` and viewing the description provided).

For example, the section that begins with "Quick reference" in the attached picture for the mariadb image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no docker-specific command line tool to get the Quick reference info from [hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com), and you can't even use a text mode web browser like `lynx` or `links` because that website displays **nothing** without javascript.

The javascript requirement means you can't even write a script (in perl or python or whatever) that parses the HTML and extracts the data you want....well, technically you could, using the [v8 javascript engine](https://v8.dev/) or similar, but that's not going to be easy - you'd essentially have to write the equivalent to a simple web browser.

This is annoying, I know - it has annoyed me for years.  But it is what it is.

If you just want to list published container images and their descriptions, you can use `docker search`.  e.g.

```
# docker search  mariadb | head
NAME                                   DESCRIPTION                                     STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
mariadb                                MariaDB Server is a high performing open sou…   4113      [OK]       
linuxserver/mariadb                    A Mariadb container, brought to you by Linux…   210                  
bitnami/mariadb                        Bitnami MariaDB Docker Image                    135                  [OK]
toughiq/mariadb-cluster                Dockerized Automated MariaDB Galera Cluster …   41                   [OK]
mariadb/server                         MariaDB Server is a modern database for mode…   37                   [OK]
colinmollenhour/mariadb-galera-swarm   MariaDb w/ Galera Cluster, DNS-based service…   33                   [OK]
panubo/mariadb-galera                  MariaDB Galera Cluster                          22                   [OK]
webhippie/mariadb                      Docker images for MariaDB                       22                   [OK]
lsioarmhf/mariadb                      ARMHF based Linuxserver.io image of mariadb     17
```

and that's it.  `docker search` doesn't display any other info, not the quick reference info, and not even a URL.

You can use the `--no-trunc` option if you don't want it to truncate the description.

```
$ docker search --help

Usage:  docker search [OPTIONS] TERM

Search the Docker Hub for images

Options:
  -f, --filter filter   Filter output based on conditions provided
      --format string   Pretty-print search using a Go template
      --limit int       Max number of search results (default 25)
      --no-trunc        Don't truncate output
```